# Why is mutual inductance coupling high in a microstrip PCB line?

Tags: pcb, high-frequency, signal-integrity, crosstalk

I am learning about crosstalk on PCBs from the high-speed signal propagation book by Howard Johnson.

It says mutual inductance coupling is high in microstrip lines compared to mutual capacitive coupling.

Why it that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is what it is. If the two tracks that make up a differential micro strip pair have a transmission impedance of 50 Ω then the ratio of inductance to capacitance is 50 squared or 2500.

Regarding cross talk, the magnetic field from a single micro strip line easily couples to an adjacent single micro strip line just like wires easily cross couple magnetically.

There is also capacitive coupling but, the "plates'" are not facing each other in a micro strip scenario hence, you can easily say that the orientation of the plates is not optimized to produce maximum cross capacitance.

But, as always, the devil is in the detail and simplified over views are a dangerous thing to make. They are what they are.